# LibGdx - Sprites moving alongside camera

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite, game-development

I am trying to render some entities in random positions on the screen. The spawning positions are okay however when I move the player entity (which the camera is focused on) and pass the middle of the screen (then the camera starts moving) the sprites of the other entities also move with me, which I do not want.

I tried giving them postions in the world and not in the screen using `cam.unproject(position);` which converts psotions relative to the screen into positions relative to the game world, but that did not work either.

They are rendered the same way all other sprites are rendered in libgdx

This is the code where I initialize the entities:

```
Texture zombie = new Texture("zombie.png");
    float x, y;
    for (int i = 0; i < enemy_amout; i++) {
        x = rm.nextFloat() * (mapWidth * 8f- zombie.getWidth());
        y = rm.nextFloat() * (mapHeight * 8f - zombie.getHeight());
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
        cam.unproject(position);
        enemies[i] = new Entity(zombie, position.x, position.y, 1);
    }
```

This is what the game looks like when I start it
[image]

And this is what it looks like after I moved the player character to the right. As you can see they moved alongside the camera but I want them to remain on their original positions.
[image]

Comment: unprojecting did not change anthing I got the same result without that line of code

Comment: batch.begin();
        player.draw(batch);

        for (Entity e: enemies) e.draw(batch);

        batch.end();

As I said just normal sprite rendering

Comment: Are you using a single camera for everything and applying its matrix to the batch?

Comment: I used one camera but I did not apply its matrix to the batch. Adding batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined); fixed my problem so thank you but now all my sprites are enormous for no reason.